# 'IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory' on website -- Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm doing some web scraping in Python and I'm running into a strange error. Sometimes when I try to open and read an html file using a URL I get the following error:

```
'IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'
```

The code that is producing this error is here: Terminal doesn't like the last line in this block of code.

```
for game in games:
            url = game
            page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

The list `games` is a list of urls that definitely exist. This is what `games` looks like when I print it out:

```
['nba.com/games/20160323/ATLWAS/gameinfo.html', 
'nba.com/games/20160323/MILCLE/gameinfo.html',
'nba.com/games/20160323/TORBOS/gameinfo.html',
'nba.com/games/20160323/ORLDET/gameinfo.html',
'nba.com/games/20160323/NYKCHI/gameinfo.html', 
'nba.com/games/20160323/UTAHOU/gameinfo.html', 
'nba.com/games/20160323/SACMIN/gameinfo.html', 
'nba.com/games/20160323/MIASAS/gameinfo.html', 
'nba.com/games/20160323/PHIDEN/gameinfo.html', 
'nba.com/games/20160323/LALPHX/gameinfo.html', 
'nba.com/games/20160323/DALPOR/gameinfo.html', 
'nba.com/games/20160323/LACGSW/gameinfo.html']
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? I actually got this error once before, and although I solved it on that occasion, I didn't understand why what I did worked so I wanted to ask the community. Previously, I had `games` set up so that instead of having the full URL, it only had part of it.

For example, the first element in the old `games` was `/games/20160323/ATLWAS/gameinfo.html`. Then in the for loop shown above, instead of `url = game`, I wrote `nba.com+url`. When I ran it with the changes outlined above, it ran as expected. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you go to the site you can see your url is not the same

Comment: I also don't think `"nba.com"+/games/20160323/ATLWAS/gameinfo.html` ever worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Python 2**:

```
for game in games:
        url = "http://" + game
        page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

(For **Python 3** you have to include .request)

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

Comment: I don't think you need to cast a string to string.

Comment: If you visit the links in `games`, the browser appends `http://www`. Maybe the OP should try the very same thing instead of just `http://`

Comment: @Goyo indeed it works. However we're talking about a python module here, not a proper web browser. Maybe the OP should try that out as well.

Comment: @Alessiox, you don't need www

Comment: @Ash-Ishh, nope, not unless they are using python3, if they were it never would have worked for any url

Comment: @Alessiox I mean it works with `urlopen()`, I tested it.

Comment: Thanks. Why does this work? I've done some web scraping before and never had to add the http:// before.